# Voltage regulation on a relay module

Tags: arduino, voltage, relay, module

I have an Arduino project which involves turning on a couple of devices which require an input voltage in excess of 5 V. I have successfully prototyped it using three [Grove-Relay modules](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Relay/).

I now want to move it to a PCB, and space is at a premium. Ideally I would like to just use the relay itself and dispense with the voltage regulation circuitry on that board. My question is whether I can do this.

Is the purpose of that circuitry to allow the relay to be switched by 3.3 V or 5 V because the relay requires 3.3 V, (i.e. steps the voltage down to 3.3 V if in excess of that is supplied to the board)? Or is it required because the 3.3 V output of an Arduino is too variable for the relay to work without it?

Comment: What are the loads to control? In some situations you can use photo MOS relays, which are much smaller and can be driven directly by Arduino pins.

Answer (score 3):

The relay on that module is the [HLS8L-DC3V-S-C](http://datasheet.octopart.com/HLS8L-DC3V-S-C-Helishun-datasheet-141446217.pdf). The datasheet shows that the relay by itself won't accept both 3.3 and 5 V, so there will be electronics to take care of that on the module, probably integrated with the driver mentioned below.

An Arduino pin can only source about 5 or 20 mA, depending on the Arduino type, and this is not enough for the relay's coil current. There will be a simple "power driver" on the module to drive the coil (which could also accept a wider range of voltages than the bare relay can, see above).

There will (hopefully) also be a flyback diode across the coil of the relay on the module, to protect the rest of the circuit.

*All* this circuitry (for voltage, current, and protection) is necessary to drive a bare mechanical relay properly from an Arduino GPIO pin.

Comment: Thanks, I can guarantee that the relay is only supplied with 3.3v but it sounds like even so the current supplied by the Arduino will not be sufficient to trigger the relay.

Comment: Sorry, stupid question but where on the data sheet is the coil current that you refer to?

Comment: I don't know (it will be in there somewhere), but it will be more than an Arduino's GPIO pin can handle.

Comment: Thanks, no minimum current specified, just minimum voltage so will try and see if it works straight off the pin.

Comment: Don't. You'll fry the pin. First try to activate the relay with a power source and measure the current, or use the coil resistance in the table at the top of page 2 of the datasheet and do the math.

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Lower voltage relay coils tend to use much more current than higher voltage ones.

So if you have some +5V or +12V available, it is better to use that for your relays. That will use less current. If 3V3 relays are powered from a 3V3 linear regulator, they will use more current than the 5V versions, which will waste more power as heat in the 3V3 regulator.

For example I have a board with 16 of [these relays](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1648381.pdf). The 24V version uses 15mA, but the 5V version uses 72mA. I used a 24V supply for the relays, and a 24V to 5V buck converter to power the microcontroller and other logic.

Comment: Thanks. I can output 5v from the Arduino so if I use a 5v relay does that mean I can do without any voltage regulation between the 5v output of the Arduino and the input to the relay itself?

Comment: No, the microcontroller can't output that current. You need a transistor or a MOSFET to switch the relay, it'll cost a few cents. Where is the arduino 5V power supply coming from? 5V wall wart?

Comment: Thanks, the Arduino is getting 10v from a buck converter which is stepping a 24v input down to 10v

Comment: If you have 24V then you can use 24V relays, it will be more efficient. You can use the cheapest available transistor (MMBT3904) with a suitable resistor plus flyback diode and it'll work. Or ULN2003.